# Calling 2 external applications at the same time

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script in which I am trying to call them out at the same time.
I have written it as:

```
os.system('externalize {0}'.format(result))
os.system('viewer {0} -b {1}'.format(img_list[0], img_list[1]))
```

However by doing so, the second application will only be open/appear unless I quit/ exit out of the first application.

I tried using `subprocess` as follows:

```
subprocess.call('externalize {0}'.format(result), shell=True)
subprocess.call('viewer {0} -b {1}'.format(img_list[0], img_list[1]))
```

But I am not getting much success. Am I doing it wrong somewhere?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just run both commands at the same time? Or make them interact somehow?

Comment: As you can see, I got 2 different outputs - `result` and `img_list`. In my code, I wrote it such that once these 2 are gathered, the 2 applications - `externalize` and `viewer` will be run together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Run them as subprocesses without waiting for finish](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=wait#subprocess.Popen):

```
p1=subprocess.Popen(<args1>)
p2=subprocess.Popen(<args2>)
```

If/when you then need to wait for their finish and/or check their exit code, call [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=wait#subprocess.Popen.wait) (or [whatever else applicable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=wait#popen-objects)) on these objects.

(In general, [you should never ignore the object that `Popen()` returns and its exit code if you need to do something as a result of the subprocess' work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964071/piping-to-ffmpeg-with-python-subprocess-freezes) (e.g. clean up the files you fed them if they're temporary).)

Answer (score 1):

Several `subprocess` functions such as `call` are just convenience wrappers for the `Popen` object which executes programs asynchronously. You can use it instead

import subprocess as subp

result = 'foo'
img_list = ['bar', 'baz']

```
proc1 = subp.Popen('externalize {0}'.format(result), shell=True)
proc2 = subp.Popen('viewer {0} -b {1}'.format(img_list[0], img_list[1]), shell=True)
proc1.wait()
proc2.wait()
```