# convert the bytes data into .mp4 and then decode that .mp4 video back into same bytes without any change in bytes data. -python

Tags: python

I have many files in a directory (.zip,.jpg,.png,.mp4,.mkv,.py,.txt etc...) . I have converted all of them into bytes using

```
with open(f'{files_path}/{file}','rb') as f:
    data=f.read()
```

and then, i have converted them into a frames of (1920,1080) size in list "frames".

now, I need to convert (encode) these byte frames into .mp4 formate. without changing any of the bytes data.

And then How to decode that .mp4 video back into same bytes which are same as frames that I encoded them before.

**MOST IMPORTANTLY, these bytes data shouldn't be changed when i convert that .mp4 video back into bytes.. Please show me a way...!

Comment: If you have decoded them to some sort of 1920x1080 frame representation, you can't get the same exact original encoded data back from those `frames`.

Comment: frames=[]
i=0
j=1
#step=frame_size**2
while (step*j)<=len(outdata):
    d=data[i:j*step]
    frames.append(d)
    i=j*step
    j+=1 code for generate frames of size 1920x1080 and encoded as for frame in frames:
    with open('output.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(frame) but the .mp4 file is correpted.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work; an MP4 file is not just a list of frames. What is your end goal? Is this a steganography project, where you're trying to hide this data in a video?

Comment: yes. I need to hide the data in .mp4 formate. But, when i retrive it back to bytes the data is lost. How ,to tackle this problem.? any algorithm or process or manipulation?

Comment: Right, you'll then need to choose a lossless video format (you'll need to do your research on suitable alternatives; you'll need something that doesn't do e.g. chroma subsampling either), and you'll probably want to come up with an encapsulation/container scheme since you'll evidently have multiple files – a `tar` might do (see the `tarfile` module). Once you've figured those out, you'll want to use e.g. `ffmpeg`'s pipe mode and feed it your frames. Then, when you read and concatenate the frames from that lossless video and un-tar it, you should get your original files back. Good luck!

Comment: actually the .avi formate stroes the data losslessly, but I need to store the data in .mp4 which stores the datal lossly. Show, change any encoding type or is there a way to store the bytes data into .mp4 without any loss?

Comment: That is incorrect. Like .mp4, .avi is also just a container for media, and that media can be encoded lossily or losslessly. (.mp4s tend to generally contain h264 or h265, which are lossy.) As I said, you will need to research which video codec suits your purposes.

Comment: What are some of  lossless codecs ? For .mp4. I have already researched a lot and could find solution. That's why i finally posted my problem here..

Comment: Surely you tried looking at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Video-Encoders and searching for "lossless"?

Comment: Yes I did. But couldn't find one. Can you suggest me a mp4 codec that doesn't perform any compression and stores the data in the same bytes. Please, help me out with this.

Comment: vp9, webp, h264, vc2 all seem to have a lossless mode.

Comment: Ok lets try vp9. Can you give me a code for this codec in python.

Comment: No, I'm not a code-writing robot. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55787179/51685 gives you an example of how to pipe frames from and to an ffmpeg subprocess; then you'll just need to plug in the correct codec.

Comment: videoname='encoded_video.avi'
fps=30
size=(frame_size[0],frame_size[1])
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'RAW ')
out=cv2.VideoWriter(videoname,codec,fps,size,isColor=False) this is the current code that i am using which preseres my data.

Comment: Yes, raw video is lossless. You'll end up with a file that has all of your original data in plain sight (try looking at `encoded_video.avi` in a text editor).

Comment: yes. its the same bytes data. I have achieved this in the first place its self. but when i try to get the same with .mp4 the bytes data is changed.